# Why is it the last data is always null

Tags: java

I have a problem getting all the data in jtable. The last data that display is always "null" even though i enter data in that cell. Can anyone help me

```
for (int i = 0; i < model_1.getRowCount(); i++) {

  if (String.valueOf(model_1.getValueAt(i, 0)) != null && !String.valueOf(model_1.getValueAt(i, 0)).isEmpty()) {
    date = String.valueOf(model_1.getValueAt(i, 0));
  }
  if (String.valueOf(model_1.getValueAt(i, 1)) != null && !String.valueOf(model_1.getValueAt(i, 1)).isEmpty()) {
    meal = String.valueOf(model_1.getValueAt(i, 1));
  }
  if (String.valueOf(model_1.getValueAt(i, 2)) != null && !String.valueOf(model_1.getValueAt(i, 2)).isEmpty()) {
    time = String.valueOf(model_1.getValueAt(i, 2));
  }
  if (String.valueOf(model_1.getValueAt(i, 3)) != null && !String.valueOf(model_1.getValueAt(i, 3)).isEmpty()) {
    activity = String.valueOf(model_1.getValueAt(i, 3));
  }
  try {
    System.out.println(date + " " + meal + " " + time + " " + activity);
  }
}
```

here is my sample output:

```
2017-10-02 sdfsd 01:30 sdfsdfsf          
2017-10-03 dsfdfs 01:00 null
```

Comment: why do you have an (incomplete) try block there? show the real code

Comment: @tgogos - did you **add** a `}` to the OP's code?

Comment: Yeah, that was me.

Comment: @tgogos I do not think it is a good idea to change the actual code as an edit

Comment: @ymak post more of your code (it's incomplete and does not even compile) and probably a sample of your data too.

Comment: Ok, I will keep that in mind next time. Thanks @ScaryWombat.

Comment: did you release the editing status on your jtable?

Comment: can you post complete code from initialization of `jTable` ? I don't know, what is the reason for upvoting this question as posted code isn't complete and god knows the data in jTable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your `jtable` is still active so the data hasn't been saved to the model yet.

Try to add this before your code:

```
if (table.isEditing())
     table.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();
```